# Flash Drive only mounts through USB Hub

Tags: usb, mount, diskutil

I have a PNY 32gb flash drive, when trying to connect the drive directly to my Mid 2012 MBP (specs attached) the drive never mounts, doesn't list in diskutil as an unmounted drive either, however when I plug the drive into a Micro Innovations USB Hub (old ~ 2002) the drive mounts (albeit slowly).

On my iMac (Mid 2010 I7) the drive works perfectly in the machine or through Apple USB Keyboard.

Any help?

[image: Mid 2012 MBP Specs]

Comment: Try plugging it into your laptop, then open Disk Utility and see if it shows up in there. It may not be mounted in the Finder, but might show up in Disk Utility.

Comment: doesn't mount in diskutility, doesn't mount through Terminal's diskutil either

Comment: Wow. Well, sadly the best thing to do is what you said you did, trash it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar thing with an old pen drive that was faulty. 
First thing I would do is go to the Console and check whether the OS complains when you insert the pen drive. In my case I would get a lot of I/O errors related to the USB device.
Reformatting and partitioning the thing with Disk Utility solved my problem (but I never trusted the drive again, I have to say)

Comment: This was a great idea, and I was seeing a lot of IO errors, the drive would stop trying to mount after 10 tries. It's in the trash now anyway.